# Mysql sort and sort again, but this does not work ORDER BY date DESC, view DESC

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've got a table with 400 entry, I do a first sort to get the latest entry and limit 20

I endup with a output limited to the latest 20 entry, order by date

```
SELECT date,view FROM `blog` order by date DESC limit 20

    date          view
    2011/08/16    18
    2011/08/15    134
    2011/08/15    20
    2011/08/13    800
    ...
```

But now I would like to sort again this output, if I try to add another sort, nothing change

```
SELECT date,view FROM `blog` order by date DESC, view DESC limit 20


    date          view
    2011/08/16    18
    2011/08/15    134
    2011/08/15    20
    2011/08/13    800
```

I would like to have

```
date          view
2011/08/13    800
2011/08/15    134
2011/08/15    20
2011/08/16    18
```

thx for your help!!!

Do I need to create a tmp table and resort this table, or is there a cleaver way of doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work; you just select from the first result set.

```
SELECT x.date, x.view FROM (SELECT date,view FROM `blog` order by date DESC limit 20) as x order by view DESC
```

What is does: it first selects the last 20 records from blog. It uses the results as input for the next SELECT that orders it descending based on view.

Comment: Just got this error, #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Is there a reason my comment got down voted after I added the alias? Is there a better way of doing this?